# Updating table in SSIS script component

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, script-component

I have table in database with these columns

```
ID  |  Fact  | Date
```

And in column `Fact` I have only `NULLs`. I want to use `Script Component` to update data in this table. Is there any way to do that?

*Note: I can't use SQL statement because of query performance.*

Comment: Is there a way to do that? Yes. But, an SQL statement will always perform better.

Comment: Update in batches. Dont use SC to do an update on SQL server. IT doesnt make sense in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script component will allow you to use C# or VB to do things. You can send database commands with C# or VB, but it's still going to end up being a SQL statement in the end.

If you can't update data in your table due to performance, you need to investigate why the performance is bad and rectify that.

Comment: I have 38 million rows to update. Maybe thats why  :(